# c# datagridview DoubleClick вывести данные из бд в новую форму

Tags: c#

в datagridview вывел некоторые данные из бд , теперь через событие DoubleClick пытаюсь вывести все данные этой строки в новую форму в текстбоксы и лабели. подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать ? проблема усложняется тем, что данные отображаются из нескольких таблиц через UNION

код выводы данных из базы в datagridview

```
public void FillDatagridview()
    {
        con.Open();

        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT summa.id, summa.cityName AS 'city1'  city1.name, satsType.name,  city1.size , year.dateTime FROM city1 LEFT JOIN summa ON city1.SummaID = summa.id LEFT JOIN satsType ON city1.satsTypeID = satsType.id LEFT JOIN year ON city1.yearID = year.id UNION  " +
         "SELECT summa.id, summa.cityName AS 'city2'  city2.name, satsType.name,  city2.size , year.dateTime FROM city2 LEFT JOIN summa ON city2.SummaID = summa.id LEFT JOIN satsType ON city2.satsTypeID = satsType.id LEFT JOIN year ON city2.yearID = year.id UNION " +
         "SELECT summa.id, summa.cityName AS 'city3'  city3.name, satsType.name,  city3.size , year.dateTime FROM city3 LEFT JOIN summa ON city3.SummaID = summa.id LEFT JOIN satsType ON city3.satsTypeID = satsType.id LEFT JOIN year ON city3.yearID = year.id UNION " +
         "SELECT summa.id, summa.cityName AS 'city4'  city4.name, satsType.name,  city4.size , year.dateTime FROM city4 LEFT JOIN summa ON city4.SummaID = summa.id LEFT JOIN satsType ON city4.satsTypeID = satsType.id LEFT JOIN year ON city4.yearID = year.id UNION " +
         "SELECT summa.id, summa.cityName AS 'city5'  city5.name, satsType.name,  city5.size , year.dateTime FROM city5 LEFT JOIN summa ON city5.SummaID = summa.id LEFT JOIN satsType ON city5.satsTypeID = satsType.id LEFT JOIN year ON city5.yearID = year.id UNION " +
         "SELECT summa.id, summa.cityName AS 'city6'  city6.name, satsType.name,  city6.size , year.dateTime FROM city6 LEFT JOIN summa ON city6.SummaID = summa.id LEFT JOIN satsType ON city6.satsTypeID = satsType.id LEFT JOIN year ON city6.yearID = year.id ", con);
        dset = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dset);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
        TableNameID = dset.ToString();
        con.Close();
    }
```

код двойного щелчка на конкретную строку

```
   public static void DublleClik(DataGridView dataGridVieww, string TableName)
    {
        Openpage openpage = new Openpage();
        openpage.summaCityName.Text = dataGridVieww.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        openpage.satsTypeName.Text = dataGridVieww.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        openpage.city1Size.Text = dataGridVieww.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        openpage.yeardateTime.Text = dataGridVieww.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        openpage.city1AmountofWorkers.Text = dataGridVieww.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        openpage.city1Kabel20x2.Text = dataGridVieww.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        openpage.city1Kabel30x2.Text = dataGridVieww.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        openpage.city1Kabel50x2.Text = dataGridVieww.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
        openpage.city1Kabel100x2.Text = dataGridVieww.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
        openpage.city1Kabel200x2.Text = dataGridVieww.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
        openpage.city1AmountofTelephones.Text = dataGridVieww.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value.ToString();
        openpage.city1AmountofFaxMachine.Text = dataGridVieww.CurrentRow.Cells[12].Value.ToString();
        openpage.city1AmountofComputers.Text = dataGridVieww.CurrentRow.Cells[13].Value.ToString();
        openpage.city1AmountofPrinters.Text = dataGridVieww.CurrentRow.Cells[14].Value.ToString();
        openpage.city1AmountofTV.Text = dataGridVieww.CurrentRow.Cells[15].Value.ToString();
        openpage.ShowDialog();
     }
```

Comment: И? Какие-то проблемы с этим кодом? Что именно не работает? Уточните.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov  метод FillDatagridview вытаскивает ограниченные данные из бд , т.к не хочу грузить datagrid, теперь же при двойном щелчке на выбранную ячейку хочу грузить другие данные связанные с id выбранной ячейки.